# Angular ui bootstrap current date (today) highlight without selecting

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular.UI Bootstrap Datepicker (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)

Now I am challenging one problem: the client always wants to see current date highlighted, even if it is not selected. Just like in this example (http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-date/).

Tried to google this problem, but no solution found for Angular.UI Bootstrap Datepicker.

There is no way, to switch to ui-date. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: you could create a custom directive with lower priority then datepickers priority (so it gets compiled after datepicker). then search todays date element and change it's style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace in the  datepicker control this

```
var days = getDates(firstDate, numDates), labels = new Array(7);
for (var i = 0; i < numDates; i++) {
  var dt = new Date(days[i]);
  days[i] = makeDate(dt, format.day, (selected && selected.getDate() === dt.getDate() && selected.getMonth() === dt.getMonth() && selected.getFullYear() === dt.getFullYear()), dt.getMonth() !== month);
}
```

with

```
var today = new Date();
var days = getDates(firstDate, numDates), labels = new Array(7);
for (var i = 0; i < numDates; i++) {
  var dt = new Date(days[i]);
  var highlight = (selected && selected.getDate() === dt.getDate() && selected.getMonth() === dt.getMonth() && selected.getFullYear() === dt.getFullYear());
    if(!highlight) {
        highlight = (today.getDate() === dt.getDate() && today.getMonth() === dt.getMonth() && today.getFullYear() === dt.getFullYear());
    }
  days[i] = makeDate(dt, format.day, highlight, dt.getMonth() !== month);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! Viva la open source and good people ! =)

Comment: Hi, this does work, but it appears to apply the same selected CSS style to  today and also the selected date. Is there any way to show a different style for each to distinguish today from the selected day?

Comment: @Holland Risley you can make the makeDate function return a json with another field such as a css style name, and then in the datepicker template make the ng-class expression (ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected}") use the css style name instead of using the 'btn-info' if "selected"

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I don't suppose you can show me how I can format this `makeDate` function call, and point me to the datepicker template?

Comment: @Holland Risley the template you can find in the "ui-bootstrap-tpls.js", just search for "{\'btn-info\': dt.selected}". You can add for example a new boolean value in the json returned by the makeDate function to tell if it's the "current day", then you would have 2 booleans "Selected" And "CurrentDay" and in the ng-class do something like this ng-class="{'btn-info':dt.Selected, 'new-css':dt.CurrentDay}

Comment: @JoaoAugusto. Can you please mention the file name? Which control/place you are referring to. Will this code will be added in controller or directive. Can you please share the code with me. Waiting for you reply.

Comment: @Ata ul Mustafa. The current .js probably is diferent now... but the change is probably still on the controller, check where they set the "selected" flag to true

Comment: Yes .js is mostly changed. Well I found an alternate solution after days of thorough internet searching.

Comment: I am using version 0.9.0 angular-ui-bootstrap
I replaced the code given above in the tpls js but it's working. Pls suggest..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the **custom-class** attribute of the datepicker.
Like this:

```
<datepicker custom-class="isToday(date, mode)" show-weeks='false' class="well well-sm" ng-model="selectedDate" ng-change="onDateSelect()"></datepicker>
```

Then you add the function on the controller:

```
$scope.isToday = function(date, mode) {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(12,0,0,0);
    if(today.toDateString() == date.toDateString() ){
        return 'today';
    }
};
```

(another option is comparing day, month and year if you prefer)

Now just the css you want to evidence the day:

```
.today button{
      background-color: #BCBCBC;}
```

**PS**: This will show the day if you change the date from today, if you want to have the current day highlighted always just make a stronger css selector to override the default '.active' class.